# How to normalize accent present in this String in Java?

Tags: java, string, normalization

I have a string, It is not getting normalized. How can I do this?

I want to compare 2 string lets say `a` and `b` as below. As can be seen `a` has accent. How can we normalize this accent and then compare the 2 string to be equal.

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

//...

String a = "nа̀ра";
String b = "nара";
a = Normalizer.normalize(a, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
a = a.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}", "");
if (!a.equals(b)) {
    System.out.println("Not Done");
}
```

Comment: What is `Normalizer`? What do you expect to happen that is not happening? What about some code that can actually be compiled and run?

Comment: @vanza please check the question. I want to compare string a and b and they should be equal after normalization.

Comment: Still, you haven't shown us what `Normalizer` is.

Comment: @vanza if you have no idea what a question is about then posting facetious comments isn't helpful. [`Normalizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) is a JDK class.

Comment: @vanza it is an inbuilt java class

Comment: My bad, I wasn't familiar with the class. Still, code that can actually be compiled is generally welcome in questions.

Comment: If I compile and run the code, `a` and `b` (after normalization) compare equal.  The accented `à` is normalized to an ordinary `a`.  Isn't this what you'd expect?

Comment: I get the same result as @5gon12eder.

Comment: No for me somehow this is not coming as equal. The above code print not done for me.